# numpy.allclose() compare arrays with floating points

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I have two numpy arrays:

```
g1 = np.array([3118740.3553, 3520175.8121])
g2 = np.array([3118740.8553, 3520176.3121])
```

I want to use `numpy.allclose()` to test if those arrays are identical inside the floating point precision tolerance

```
np.allclose(g1, g2, atol=1e-7)
```

Curiously it returns `True` even if the difference between those two arrays is significant. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [call signature of `np.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) is

```
In [4]: np.allclose?
Signature: np.allclose(a, b, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08, equal_nan=False)
```

Notice that the default for `rtol` (relative tolerance) is 1e-05.
As long as

```
abs(a[i] - b[i]) <= rtol * abs(b[i]) + atol
```

for all `i = 0, ..., len(a)`, then `np.allclose` returns True.

```
In [11]: rtol, atol = 1e-05, 1e-7

In [12]: [abs(ai - bi) < rtol * abs(bi) + atol for ai, bi in zip(g1, g2)]
Out[12]: [True, True]
```

---

Since the values in `g2` are large, even a small `rtol` leads to a fairly large tolerance:

```
In [14]: rtol * g2.min()
Out[14]: 31.187408553
```

---

If you don't want to include a relative tolerance, you must set it to zero to override the default:

```
In [13]: np.allclose(g1, g2, rtol=0, atol=1e-7)
Out[13]: False
```